# PHP MySQL times out when updating large db

Tags: php, mysql, json, rest

I have a MySQL database with about 6 million song IDs on an external provider with chrooted access to command line.

I get Bad Gateway error at about record 450, even if it keeps updating till about record 950. It's far from the full db and I don't really know how to handle it. I also tried to limit the query, but as said it will stops and a manual split is impossible (6000 handwritings!!!)

A flow overview is as follows, pseudocode after for deeper understanding:

1. retrieve song IDs from a table
2. query for details an external API (REST with json results)
3. insert the full song details in a different table

Thank you in advance for help.

*PSEUDOCODE*

```
ini_set('max_execution_time',0);//INFINITE
ini_set("memory_limit", "300M");//MAX SUPPORTED BY HOSTING

$query1 = "SELECT id FROM songs";
$sql = mysqli_query($link, $query1) or die("error");

while ( $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql) ) {
    $url = 'https://api.com/tracks?pass='.$pass.'&id='.$row["id"];
    $content = file_get_contents($url);
    $json = json_decode($content, true);//RETURNS "results" ARRAY

    $query2 = "INSERT INTO songs_ok VALUES ";

    foreach($json["results"] as $result){
        $query2.= "( ";
        $query2.= $row["timestamp"].",";
        $query2.= $row["artist"].",";
        $query2.= " ),";

        $query2 = rtrim($query2,", ").";";

        $sql2 = mysqli_query($link, $query2) or die("error");

    }

}
```

p.s. I also tried to put the INSERT query at bottom, but obviously the result is almost the same. Thx

Comment: Why not batch your inserts?  `INSERT INTO table (col1, cols2) VALUES (record1, record1), (record2, record2), (record3, record3), etc...` - You can insert AFAIK hundreds of records at once, rather than hitting the DB with a query for each one.  Additionally, inserts are "expensive" when you have indexes (which I would hope you do), so it seems with 6m records - AFAIK - that the indexes have to be re-calculated with each insert.  With a fast-running loop like this, and lots of records, it would seem that batching the inserts at least would help.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST` or `$_GET` data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: @cate_b Unluckily I was unclear. As you can read in the post scriptum, I already tried unsuccessfully to batch insert.

Comment: @tadman the scripts are not exposed to the internet. I need to do this update and then delete the script, it's an historical db.

Comment: It's a super bad habit to get into, and "it's not exposed to the internet" is no excuse. Code has a way of being re-used in the future on other projects because it seems to work, where people are unaware of the huge liability they're deploying. Doing it with `bind_param` is actually easier than this `(intval)` casting nonsense.

Comment: I remember we're talking about pseudocode, so i will delete any reference  specific to OFF TOPIC matters. Thanks indeed for your advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was an hardcoded limit.
The workaround which have been perfectly working until today

```
mysqli_query($link, "set @@session.interactive_timeout = 28800");
mysqli_query($link, "set @@session.wait_timeout = 28800");
```

Comment: Still you can try and setting your maximum execution time to infinite, and check php console application settings if you can. 

And also, mark my answer as correct. :)

Comment: bash inline for loop 6500 times? In case of results = 0 it just would skip any update to db...

Comment: I think single line loop won't make any difference at all.

Answer (score -1):

First: as @cale_b suggested, you should insert in batches which means inserting more records in a single query like `INSERT INTO table (col1, cols2) VALUES (record1, record1), (record2, record2), (record3, record3), etc...`

Second: you should retrieve your data from the table in batches. Meaning, retrieve for example 100 rows at a time (it's done with LIMIT in sql's SELECT and with OFFSET).

The first thing will keep your database server from overloading, the second thing will keep your memory from overloading.

Also, take into a consideration that some web services, like Cloudflare have maximum execution time set to a specific time that you CANNOT change. You should then run your script as a console application, as running scripts in console have no maximum execution times.

You can call your console script from a web application with a simple command:

```
$command = 'php /path/to/your_script.php > /dev/null 2>/dev/null &';

shell_exec($command);
```

The added `> /dev/null 2>/dev/null &` will start console application in an independant process, so it won't be connected to your web app and won't break if a web app process stops.

Comment: hello, perhaps I was unclear. As you can read in the post scriptum, I already tried unsuccessfully to batch insert. I also tried LIMIT 1000 but it times out indeed at "about" record 950: it's impossible to check 6500 times where it stops, recalculate the offset and hardcode it 6500 times.

Comment: There is also one more thing I forgot to mention, some web servers have maximum execution time set to a specific time and you cannot change it, like cloudfare has 100 seconds. I solved that by making a cron job that will run through console instead. Take that into a consideration, I will also update my answer.

Comment: Changing engine to InnoDB and aggressive indexing strategy solved almost all my performance problems